# Monoidal closed category-correctness of domain and codomain of a functor $(-)^*$

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I do not follow in the sinppet below how from the fact that
$({\cal K},\otimes,I)$ is a symmetric monoidal closed category
follows that the functor
$$[-,D]:\cal K\to K^{op}$$
has domain $\cal K$ and codomain $\cal K^{op}$ ?
Perhaps I would also need to recall the definition of
a symmetric monoidal closed category.
I **understand** that $[X,D]$ is the set of all functors from $X$ to $D$.

[image]

Comment: You should recall the definition of symmetric monoidal category. $[X,D]$ is *not* the set of functors from $X$ to $D$, which doesn't even make sense because $X$ and $D$ are objects and $[X,D]$ is an object of $\mathcal K$, not $\mathbf{Set}$. This is the notation for an internal hom. It is the case that *in $\mathbf{Cat}$* the internal hom, $[\mathcal C,\mathcal D]$, is the *category* for functors from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal D$. This is just one instance of this idea though.

Comment: $[X,D]$ is contravariant in $X$ in the $\mathbf{Cat}$ (as in every case). The contravariance comes from the universal property and the contravariance of the external hom. Maybe the fact that this is written as $\mathcal K\to\mathcal K^{op}$ rather than equivalently as $\mathcal K^{op}\to\mathcal K$ is what is making this seem unusual?

Comment: A contravariant functor from $C$ to $D$ can be written either as a functor $C^{op} \to D$ or as a functor $C \to D^{op}$.

Comment: I **do not have problems with co(ntra)variance**  but with the fact that $[X,D]$ is not in $\text{Set}$ but in $\cal K^{op}$. How the cartesian closedness is used to see that $[X,D]$ lies in $\cal K^{op}$ and not in $\text{Set}$?

Comment: Then you even more need to review [the definition of a symmetric monoidally closed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category) as this is true by definition and $\mathbf{Set}$ isn't involved anywhere in the definition.

Comment: @DerekElkins Great. So $[X,D]$ is already and immediately  a part of the monoidal closed category right?